# Uploading file with PHP and PowerShell

Tags: php, powershell

I want to upload to my website via PowerShell.

When I use a simple HTML file the uploaded file appears in the folder, but when I use PowerShell I get the error code 200 and the file is not uploaded.

I am using this code (source: [PHP File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)):

PHP:

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and PowerShell:

```powershell
Invoke-Webrequest -URI "https://example.com/upload.php" -Method POST -InFile "C:\Users\markus\Desktop\abc.png" -Debug
```

This is the error/debug message that I get:

```powershell
DEBUG: POST with -1-byte payload
DEBUG: received 114-byte response of content type text/html; charset=UTF-8


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : 
                    Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Vary: User-Agent
                    Content-Length: 114
                    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
                    Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2022 17:29:37 GMT
                    Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix)
                    X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.17
```

So, what I am doing false and how should I use the Invoke-WebRequest command correct to upload an image?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your PS-Script

`200` is actually not an error but an success [http status-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success). Would the PS script upload the file if no file is available? If yes, I would simple delete the existing file:

Replace the block `Check if file already exists` with `Delete file if existing`

```php
//  Delete file if existing
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uploadOk = unlink($target_file) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. The PHP-script does not work with your change too. I get this: `Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.`

Comment: just for testing purposes please comment out wit `//`  the five lines below `// Allow certain file formats`

Comment: It doesn't work either. Now I get this: `Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.`

Comment: you may misunderstood. I've created a [gist with the changes](https://gist.github.com/lordisp/3a6fa459e69cc21f91a30e82862f6d1c). Please try and let me know.

Comment: After I have copied and tested your code, I get this information: `Sorry, your file was not uploaded.`

Comment: I've updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/lordisp/3a6fa459e69cc21f91a30e82862f6d1c). if you have php on your local machine, change in that directory where the upload.php and upload folder is with your powershell. Then type ` php -S localhost:3001` or any other available port. Got to `http://localhost:3001/upload.php` and try the upload function. You can ignore the initial `Warning`. This is just because there's no post body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243595/discussion-between-lordisp-and-jjb).